# How can I make my script save in PDF only the first sheet with a certain range. currently save the entire file

Tags: google-apps-script

This code I currently use, only the problem is that it keeps the whole book...

```
function PDFP()
{

var file = null;

var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName());

if ( files.hasNext() )

file = files.next();

var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(file.getAs('application/pdf'));

var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F6").getValues();

var values2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D11").getValues();

  Logger.log(values["F6"]);

  Logger.log(values2["D11"]);

newFile.setName("No." + " " + values + " " + values2);

   var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();

        var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1MZVNcUnoNs63_rDhCyydH8jZGLr5JjZO");

        destination.addFile(file);

        var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

        pull.removeFile(file);   

      Browser.msgBox("Tu documento ha sido guardado con éxito." , Browser.Buttons.OK);
}

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Using the Drive API, Spreadsheets that are exported contain **all** sheets that are in the Spreadsheet. If you wish to use DriveApp to export a range, you must first copy the range to a new Spreadsheet and export it.*

#### Relevant methods:

You can use the  `create()` method of `SpreadsheetApp` to create a new file, and then the `getRange()` and `copyTo()` methods to isolate them for exporting. From here you can use the relevant `DriveApp` methods to create your `PDF`.

#### Example code:

```js
// Create temporary Sheet and copy the range from your current Sheet:
var tempSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Sheet para exportar');
var rangeToExport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("YOUR-RANGE");

// Copy previously copied range to new Sheet:
var numRows = rangeToExport.getNumRows();
var numColumns = rangeToExport.getNumColumns();
rangeToExport.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns))

// Create and name the new PDF:
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F6").getValues();
var values2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D11").getValues();
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(tempSheet.getAs('application/pdf'));
newFile.setName("No." + " " + values + " " + values2);

// Add the new PDF to Drive and delete the temporaryt Sheet:
DriveApp.getFolderById("YOUR-DRIVE-FOLDER-ID").addFile(newFile);
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(tempSheet);
```

#### References:

- [Method `SpreadsheetApp.create()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname)
- [Method `Spreadsheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getrangea1notation)
- [Method `Range.copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#copytodestination)